# Get bookmark tags

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, bookmarks, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to build a WebExtension that exports all data of bookmarks.
It's easy. There are beautiful docs for [`bookmarks.getTree()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/getTree).
But, I did not find how to get the bookmark's tags (the part in red on the picture)

How get tag of bookmarks?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### Bookmark tag information is not currently available to WebExtensions based add-ons.

WebExtensions have only limited access to the data that is contained in a Firefox bookmark. The information that is available to WebExtensions is only the data that is contained in the [`bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode` Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNode). Specifically, this includes only ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNode)):

> - `id` A [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) which uniquely identifies the node. Each ID is unique within the user's profile and remains unchanged across browser restarts.
> - `parentId`
>     A [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) which specifies the ID of the parent folder. This property is not present in the root node.
> - `index`
>     A number which represents the zero-based position of this node within its parent folder, where zero represents the first entry.
> - `url`
>     A [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) which represents the URL for the bookmark. If the node represents a folder, this property is omitted.
> - `title`
>     A [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) which contains the text displayed for the node in menus and lists of bookmarks.
> - `dateAdded`
>     A number representing the creation date of the node in [milliseconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
> - `dateGroupModified`
>     A number representing the date and time the contents of this folder last changed, in [milliseconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
> - `unmodifiable`
>     A [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) as described by the type [`bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNodeUnmodifiable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNodeUnmodifiable). Represents the reason that the node can't be changed. If the node can be changed, this is omitted.
> - `children`
>     An [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array) of [`bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNode) objects which represent the node's children. The list is ordered in the list in which the children appear in the user interface. This field is omitted if the node isn't a folder.
> - `type`
>     A [`bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNodeType) object indicating whether this is a bookmark, a folder, or a separator. Defaults to `"bookmark"` unless `url` is omitted, in which case it defaults to `"folder"`.

This specifically does not contain the tags, nor any of the other possible annotations which can be associated with a bookmark. None of this additional information is available to WebExtensions.

If you want to access this information from a WebExtension, you could create an API using a [WebExtensions experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which would do what you desire. There is already some work being done by others. As mentioned by [e-motiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301753/e-motiv) in a comment, the bug tracking this issue is [Bug 1225916 - Allow reading and writing bookmark tags](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225916).

All [other types of Firefox extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324) have access to all information stored in a Firefox bookmark.

Comment: Firefox bug for this:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225916

Answer (score 1):

Since the WebExtensions API does not currently support bookmarks tags, one alternative (as suggested above) is to create a WebExtension Experiment API. I needed something similar so I created a [WebExtension Experiment API for tags](https://github.com/azappella/webextension-experiment-tags) to expose some of the internal Firefox API for tags, thus enabling users/developers to access/read/retrieve bookmark tags in their own extensions. Hopefully, this can help someone.